# Have a trouble with まで

Tags: translation

> 私がびくびく怯えて過ごしてるせいで、彼まで過敏になってる気がする

This まで confusing me. In this case it's translating like "even", right?

Comment: My first instinct would be that it means something similar to what we would say in English when we say "I've had it up to here!" (まで meaning "up to" in this case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, まで is an intensifier and "even" is a valid translation.

[彼]{かれ}まで[過敏]{かびん}になってる ＝ 彼さえ過敏になってる

Answer (score 2):

`まで` has several meanings, but always includes some notion of range. Here it means that the range of people becoming over-sensible due to the narrator's fears extends **up to** 「彼」.

As the dictionary says, the word `まで` suffixes represents the boundary of the range, emphasizing its extent (thus `even` seems like a proper translation since it conveys the same nuance of emphasize):

> 事態の及ぶ範囲がある限界にまで達することを表す。[1](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7)

Note that this is different from for example `彼も`, which too would work here but would only state another person affected (`he too`) without giving the notion of other people of things included in the range between the narrator and 「彼」.